# View active SQL database

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I previously encountered an error in which the SQL table within visual studio seemingly didn't update as it should after the save button was pressed in the windows form. (described in detail [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8b6db17-b622-4de5-949c-f948a5c4dcc7/why-does-my-database-store-data-to-my-dataset-temporarily?forum=vblanguage#1777ee16-660e-48ca-acc6-6555f2cb1a7e)) I have since resolved this using the method posted regarding changing `Copy to output directory` to `Copy if newer`.

This runs and allows the changes made in the Windows Forms application to be maintained through successive runs.

My question is: how do I go about viewing the data stored in the table through Visual Studio? Because the SQL Server table there still contains the original data and does not update along with the changes made on the Windows Form. Also will data entered persist through powering / depowering the machine? (I assume this has no effect)

Comment: Please tell us what **concrete database system** this is for - many things are vendor-specific. Are you using MySQL? Postgres? SQL Server? Oracle? IBM DB2? Something else entirely? Please update your tags to show what database system (and which version of it!) you're using - thanks!

Comment: Would you be able to help me identify which is being used? I'd assume SQL Server but I'm not entirely sure. I created the database using `service-based database` in visualstudio which only provides the description: `An empty SQL server database for service-based data access`. Sorry for my ignorance, I'm new and this is my first time working with SQL and visual studio's database features

Comment: Yes, that is a `.mdf` file - a full-fledged SQL Server database file.

Comment: Which **version** of Visual Studio are you using? 2010? 2012? 2013? 2015?

Comment: That would be Visual studio 2013^

Comment: Can you edit your question so that someone will be able to understand it without clicking the link in the first sentence?

Comment: Question has been edited